# How do I get Sublime Text 2 to reload files when they change on the disk?

Tags: git, sublimetext2

How do I get sublime to reload the files when I switch git branches?  Is it supposed to be doing this automatically?  This question hasn't been asked anywhere on here, and I haven't been able to find anything via google.

Answer (score 2):

It should do it automatically. On Windows 8 I have a file open in one branch, switch over to the command line, checkout another branch, switch back to Sublime, and the file's contents are reloaded automatically. You may need to switch to another tab in Sublime, then switch back to the file. If there are unsaved changes in the first branch, you should be asked if you want to reload the file.

Comment: This doesn't just automatically happen for me.  Do you have to use the paid version?

Comment: @user14346436  - I apologize for the late response.  MattDMo is right.  I ran into this with a network file, where I was making changes with one computer and wanting to refresh the contents on another.  Even on a network file, changing focus away from Sublime Text, then back worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Happens automatically on OSX Mavericks when you switch branches (non-paid version of Sublime).

Comment: I can confirm @mickm's answer. file reload is about 10 sec apart (if not more). So wait...